# Allow additional properties in reference schemas, but none else

Tags: jsonschema

Suppose I have two schema being used to validate a json file.

**testSchema.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "$schema": { "type": "string" },
        "sample": { "type": "number" }
    },
    "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "./testSchema2.json" },
        {}
    ]
}
```

**testSchema2.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "test": { "type": "string" },
        "test2": { "type": "number" }
    }
}
```

**test.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "../testSchema.json",
    "sample": 0,
    "test": "some text" //this line throws error "Property is not allowed"
}
```

I'd like for the file to be validated against the included schema's properties and any schema that is referenced's properties. Am I missing something?

Edit: I want to exclude any objects that are not explicitly defined in any of my included/referenced schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From JSON Schema draft `2019-09` (after `draft-07`), this is possible by using the `unevaluatedProperties` keyword.

`additionalProperties` cannot "see through" applicator keywords such as "anyOf" and "$ref", and only works based on the properties in the same schema object.

This is not possible with `draft-07` or previous.

Comment: If you're looking for further details, apologies, our documentation isn't the MOST up to date. You may check out this recording of a conference talk I gave a few weeks ago which mentions this keyword: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kNLrpce_lg

Comment: Is there an easy way to designate draft 2019-09 rather than draft-07? I'm not seeing any online example of people using that version. VS/VSCode suggests its not fully supported.l

Comment: You set `"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema"`, but you have to be using an implementation that supports it. There aren't as many as draft-07, but it's increasing. See https://json-schema.org/implementations.html